# Changing proxy settings automatically when connecting to different wifi networks

Tags: firefox, proxy, internet-explorer, wifi-configuration

I connect to multiple wifi networks at home and work every day and I find changing the proxy settings for my browsers all day long to be a waste of life.

From previous questions, I find information on changing IP settings on different networks or changing proxy based on different URLs hit but not changing proxies based on wifi network connecting to.

How would you automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build in tool for that in Windows, You will need a "Connection Manager" tool like [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/) (or any [other alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/netsetman/) to it), which allow you to set all the system properties for each network you connected to.

Also some Laptop manufacturers have a similar application for their computers, but from my experience i didn't find any tools which allow the functionality like NetSetMan.